# Ошибка в триггере "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error" при сравнении только HH24:MI

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Необходимо создать триггер, который будет проверять, что время начала не раньше 09:00 и не позже 18:00. Tриггер создался, но при внесении данных выводятся  такие ошибки:

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
>       ORA-06512: at "DECANAT.CORRECT_TIMETIBLE", line 2
>       ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'DECANAT.CORRECT_TIMETIBLE'

Триггер:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Correct_TimeTible
INSTEAD of Insert ON Timetable1
BEGIN
if  to_char(:new.DATE_BEGIN, 'hh24:mi') >= to_char('9:00', 'hh24:mi') and 
to_char(:new.DATE_BEGIN, 'hh24:mi') <= to_char('16.30', 'hh24:mi') 
then Insert into Timetable values (:new.ID_TIMETABLE,:new.ID_SUBJECT,:new.ID_TEACHER,:new.ID_TYPE,:new.DATE_BEGIN);
ELSE dbms_output.put_line('Incorrected time');
end if;
END;
```

Создание таблицы TIMETABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE  "TIMETABLE" 
(   "ID_TIMETABLE" NUMBER, 
"ID_SUBJECT" NUMBER, 
"ID_TEACHER" NUMBER, 
"ID_TYPE" NUMBER, 
"DATE_BEGIN" DATE, 
 CONSTRAINT "TIMETABLE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_TIMETABLE") ENABLE, 
 CONSTRAINT "SUB_TIME_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("ID_SUBJECT")
  REFERENCES  "SUBJECT" ("ID_SUBJECT") ENABLE, 
 CONSTRAINT "TEACH_TIME_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("ID_TEACHER")
  REFERENCES  "TEACHER" ("ID_TEACHER") ENABLE, 
 CONSTRAINT "TYPE_TIME_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("ID_TYPE")
  REFERENCES  "TYPE_SUBJECT" ("ID_TYPE") ENABLE
)
/
```

Вставка для проверки работы триггера:

```
insert into Timetable1 (ID_TIMETABLE,ID_SUBJECT,ID_TEACHER,ID_TYPE,DATE_BEGIN) 
values (SEQ_TIMETABLE.nextval,'1','3','1',to_date('20.05.2018 15:00','dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')
);
```

Comment: Добавьте,пожалуйста, к вопросу скрипт создания таблицы, и `insert` который вы делаете. И ошибку текстом напишите, а не картинкой

Comment: Зачем вообще сверять строки вместо чисел? И почему в условии 18, а в примере 16:30?

Comment: вы не правильно написали `to_char('9:00', 'hh24:mi')`. Не очень понятно, что вы вообще тут хотите сделать. Возможно стоит просто сравнить даты, без всяких ту чаров

Comment: Мне нужно проверка на то, чтобы пара не начиналась раньше 9.00 любого дня, и заканчивалась не позднее 18.00, поэтому в коде 16.30

Comment: Вам лучше тогда использовать `extract` функцию. Извлекайте отдельно часы и минуты и сравнивайте полученные данные уже как числа

Comment: EXTRACT с часами не подойдёт же для DATE?

Comment: Разве через cast не сработает? `extract (hour from cast (dе as timestamp) ) hour`?

Comment: мне нужны часы и минуты

Comment: часы я написал. А минуты `extract (minute from cast (de as timestamp)) minute`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Замените условие в триггере на:

```
if  to_char(:new.date_begin, 'hh24mi') >= '0900' and 
    to_char(:new.date_begin, 'hh24mi') <= '1630'
then 
    ...
```

---

Или можно сравнить как разницу в часах и минутах (чисел) завернув преобразование в функцию, например:

```
create or replace function toMinuteOfDay (dt date) return number is
begin
    return extract(hour from cast (dt as timestamp))*60 + extract(minute from cast (dt as timestamp)); 
end;
/
select toMinuteOfDay (to_date('20.05.2018 16:30', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')) "MinuteOfDay" 
from dual;

MinuteOfDay
------------
       990
```

Но никакого преимущества в производительности такое [сравнение](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2048810500346778955) не даст.

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло)

Comment: Рад был помочь.